# Practical example of MVD3: (transitivity) If X ↠ Y and Y ↠ Z, then X ↠ (Z − Y)

Tags: database, normalization, database-normalization

I was learning database normalization and join dependencies and
5NF. I had a hard time. Can anyone give me some practical examples of the multivalue dependency rule:

MVD3: (transitivity) If X ↠ Y and Y ↠ Z, then X ↠ (Z − Y).

Comment: One of the difficulties with MVDs tends to be finding plausible examples.

Comment: Check this 30 years old article that explains normal forms by example: http://www.bkent.net/Doc/simple5.htm (*"A Simple Guide to Five Normal Forms in Relational Database Theory"*)

Answer (score 1):

Functional dependency / Normalization theory and the normal forms up to and including BCNF, were developed on the hypothesis of all data attributes (columns/types/...) being "atomic" in a certain sense.  That "certain sense" has long been deprecated by now, but essentially it boiled down to the notion that "a single cell value in a table could not itself hold a multiplicity of values".  Think, a textual CSV list of ISBN numbers, a table appearing as a value in a cell in a table (truly nested tables), ...

Now imagine an example with courses, professors, and study books used as course material.  Imagine all of that modeled in a single 3-column table which says that "Professor (P) teaches course (C) and uses book (B) as course material."  If there can be more than one book (B) used for any given course (Cn) and there can be more than one course (C) taught by any given professor (Pn) and there can be more than one professor (P) teaching any given course (Cn), then this table is clearly all-key (key is the full set of attributes {P,C,B} ).

This means that this table satisfies BCNF.

But now imagine that there is a rule to the effect that "the *set* of books used for any given course (Cn) must be the same, regardless of which professor teaches it.".

In the days when normalization was developed to the form in which it is now commonly known, it was not allowed to have table columns (relation attributes) that were themselves tables (relations).  (Because such a design was considered a violation of 1NF, a notion which is now considered suspect.)

Imagine for a moment that we are indeed allowed to model relation attributes to be of type relation.  Then we could model our 3-column table (/relation) as follows : "Professor (P) teaches course (C) and uses *THE SET OF BOOKS* (SB) as course material.".  Attribute SB would no longer be an ISBN number, as in the previous and more obvious design, but it would be a (probably unary) *RELATION* holding the entire set of ISBN numbers.  If we draw our design like that, and we then consider our rule that "all professors use the same set of books for the same course", then we see that this rule is now expressible as an FD from (C) to (SB) !!!  And this means that we have a violation of a lower NF on our hand !!!

4 and 5 NF have arisen out of this kind of problems (where the appearance of a single attribute value -courseID (C)- causes a requirement for the appearance of *A MULTITUDE* of rows (multiple (B) ISBn numbers) being recognised quite early on, but without the solution that is currently regarded as the best (RVA's), being recognised as a valid one.  So 4 and 5 NF were created "new and further normal forms", where the then-existing definitions of 2, 3 and BC NF were already sufficient for dealing with the situation at hand, provided RVA's had been recognised as a valid design approach.

To support that claim, let's look at what whould be done to eliminate the NF violation in our {P,C,SB} design with the FD C->SB :

We would split the table into two separate tables {P,C} and {C,SB} with keys {P,C} and {C}, repsectively.  Both tables satisfy BCNF.

But we still have this SB attribute that holds a *set* of ISBN numbers.  Dealing with this can be done by applying a technique like "UNGROUPING".  Applying this to our {C,SB} table would get us a {C,B} table, where B are the ISBN book numbers (or whatever identifier you like to use in your database), and the key to the table is {C,B}.  This is exactly the same design we would get if we eliminated the 4/5 NF violation !!!

You might also want to take a look at [Multivalue Dependency violation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963832/multivalue-dependency-violation/8010728#8010728)